# Python groupby multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

I have a dataframe like this

[Original DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZd0a.png)

How can I add one more index and groupby like:

[Desired Output DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lok1Z.png)

Many Thanksssss!

Comment: Is that a pandas DataFrame or an Excel screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Sembei. It is an Excel screenshot as I dont know how can I create my desired dataframe in python....

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['11/1/2018']*5+['11/2/2018']*5,
                   'Stock':['AAPL','SHOP','FB','F','C']*2, 
                   'Price':np.random.randint(20,75,10)})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df.set_index(df['Date'], append=True)\
  .rename_axis(['Index','DateGroup'], axis=0)\
  .swaplevel(0,1)\
  .sort_index()
```

Output:

```
                       Date Stock  Price
DateGroup  Index                        
2018-11-01 0     2018-11-01  AAPL     26
           1     2018-11-01  SHOP     21
           2     2018-11-01    FB     65
           3     2018-11-01     F     55
           4     2018-11-01     C     47
2018-11-02 5     2018-11-02  AAPL     45
           6     2018-11-02  SHOP     67
           7     2018-11-02    FB     24
           8     2018-11-02     F     52
           9     2018-11-02     C     47
```